# Strange behavior of Hibernate in asynchronous EJB application. Race Condition?

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa, concurrency

BRIEF DESCRIPTION OF THE PROBLEM:

I am working on Java EE application processing messages from financial markets. Application is deployed on application Server: **Wildfly-8.2.0.Final**.

Flow of messages in application illustrates the following diagram:

```
MDB1
     \
      StrategyManager(@Singleton) -> StrategyRunner(@Singleton) -> SomeStrategy(@Singleton)
     /
MDB2
```

Asynchronously called EJB - SomeStrategy(@Singleton) is performing Read|Update operation on JPA model defined as JPA Entities:
StrategyEntity-< ParamEntity [ParamEntity is in @ManyToOne, FetchType.EAGER, CascadeType.ALL relation to StrategyEntity].

**StrategyManager** and **StrategyRunner** are helper EJBs decoupling i.e. database operation form main business logic contained in **SomeStrategy(@Singleton)**.

StrategyEntity is refreshed before and saved after Read|Update operations performed by SomeStrategySingletonEJB.

```
@Slf4j
@Singleton
@Local
@Startup
public class StrategyRunner {

    @EJB
    private SomeStrategySingletonEJB someStrategySingletonEJB;

    @EJB
    private StrategyDao strategyDao;


    public void runStrategy(StrategyEntity strategyEntity, OrderBookAggregated orderBookAggregated) {
        strategyDao.refresh(strategyEntity);
        log.info("StrategyEntity after refresh: {}", startegyEntity);
        if (!strategyEntity.isRunning()) return;

        someStrategySingletonEJB.updateOnOrderBook(strategyEntity);
        log.info("StrategyEntity before save: {}", startegyEntity);
        strategyDao.save(strategyEntity);

    }

    public void runStrategy(StrategyEntity strategyEntity, OrderQueryReport orderQueryReport) {
        strategyDao.refresh(strategyEntity);
        log.info("StrategyEntity after refresh: {}", startegyEntity);
        if (!strategyEntity.isRunning()) return;
        someStrategySingletonEJB.updateOnExecutionReport(strategyEntity, orderQueryReport);
        log.info("StrategyEntity before save: {}", startsingletoneegyEntity);
        strategyDao.save(strategyEntity);
    }

}
```

Methods runStrategy() are called concurrently from MDBs. Default lock type of Singleton is WRITE lock so methods should
never run concurrently. StrategyEntity is retrieved from database in upper layer (StrategyManager) see DETAIL description.
**The problem is: Sometimes (very rear - once on 2000 messages on average) "StrategyEntity before save" differs
"StrategyEntity after refresh"!** It looks like some kind of race condition. If I replace strategyDao (accessing RDBMS)
with simple cache implemented as EJB @Singleton, the problem disappears. I deduce problem with
Hibernate operations as **application after replacing database layer with Cache works perfectly under heavy workload**. Do you have any ideas?

Hibernate properties:

```
<persistence-unit name="AlgorithmEnginePU">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>java:jboss/AlgorithmEngineDS</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <!--<class>com.main.model.configuration.ExchangeInformation</class>-->
    <properties>

        <!-- Properties for Hibernate -->
        <property name="hibernate.default_schema" value="algorithm_engine"/>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
        <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.JBossAppServerJtaPlatform"/>
        <!--<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />-->
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

---

DETAIL DESCRIPTION OF THE PROBLEM:

Here is the first MDB. When strategyManager is locked, received message is not queued nor processed and onMessage() returns without any EJB call.
Let me note that serialized OrderBookEntity is only transfer object and is used only as POJO.

```
@MessageDriven(name = "OrderBookTReceiver", activationConfig = {
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationLookup", propertyValue = "jms/quotationData"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Topic"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "acknowledgeMode", propertyValue = "Auto-acknowledge"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "subscriptionDurability", propertyValue = "NonDurable")})
@DependsOn({"OrderBookManager"})
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)
public class OrderBookReceiver implements MessageListener{

    @EJB
    private StrategyManager strategyManager;

    @EJB
    private StrategyOrderBookLock strategyLock;

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {

        if (message instanceof ObjectMessage) {
            ObjectMessage objectMessage = (ObjectMessage) message;
            try {
                Serializable serializable = objectMessage.getObject();

                if (serializable instanceof OrderBookEntity) {
                    OrderBookEntity orderBookEntity = (OrderBookEntity) serializable;

                        if(strategyLock.tryLock()){
                            try {
                                strategyManager.updateOrderBook(orderBookEntity);
                            }finally{
                                strategyLock.unlock();
                            }
                        }
                }
            } catch (JMSException e) {
                log.error(e.toString());
            }


        }
    }
}
```

The second MDB receives other types of messages and queues them for processing on injected Singletons as they
follow default WRITE_LOCK:

```
@Slf4j
@MessageDriven(name = "MessageReceiver", activationConfig = {
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationLookup", propertyValue = "jms/tradeAgentReply"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Topic"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "acknowledgeMode", propertyValue = "Auto-acknowledge")})
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)
public class TradeAgentClientMDB implements MessageListener {

    @EJB
    private StrategyManager strategyManager;

    @Override
    public void  onMessage(Message message) {
        (...)

        try {

            TradeQueryReport tradeQueryReport = (TradeQueryReport) serializableMessage;

           if (tradeQueryReport instanceof OrderQueryReport ) {
                OrderQueryReport orderQueryReport = (OrderQueryReport) tradeQueryReport;
                strategyManager.updateOrder(orderQueryReport);
            }

        } catch (JMSException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Here goes EJBs (StrategyRunner @EJB was  described in BRIEF DESCRIPTION section):

```
@Slf4j
@Singleton
@Local
@Startup
public class StrategyManager {

    @Inject
    private StrategyDao strategyDao;

    @EJB
    private StrategyRunner strategyRunner;

    @Asynchronous
    public void updateOrderBook(OrderBookAggregated orderBookAggregated) {

        StrategyEntity strategy =  strategyDao.findStrategyByExchange(orderBookAggregated.getAccount().getExchangeEntity());

        if(strategyEntity == null) return;

        strategyRunner.runStrategy(strategyEntity, orderBookAggregated);
    }

    @Asynchronous
    public void updateOrder(OrderQueryReport orderQueryReport) {

        StrategyEntity strategy = strategyDao.findStrategyByOrder(orderQueryReport.getClientOrderId());

        if(strategy == null) return;

        strategyRunner.runStrategy(strategy, orderQueryReport);
    }

    (...)
}

@Singleton
@Local
@Startup
public class StrategyOrderBookLock {
    private java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock updateOrderBookLock = new ReentrantLock();


    @Lock(LockType.READ)
    public boolean tryLock() {
        return updateOrderBookLock.tryLock();
    }

    @Lock(LockType.READ)
    public void unlock() {
        updateOrderBookLock.unlock();
    }
}
```

Comment: In your `OrderBookReceiver`, you never use `orderBookEntity`. Instead, there is a new variable `orderBookAggregated`. Typo?

Comment: Questions: How do you know `StrategyRunner` is a singleton? Also make sure that the lock is really a singleton - just to be safe. To make sure that the log entries aren't from different threads, add the thread ID to the log file. Lastly, do you log synchronously?

Comment: Yes it was a Typo. I corected it, thanks! I don't know if I understand your question correctly... StrategyRunner is a Singleton because it is annotated with EJB @Singleton. Lock is also Singleton with default lock type change to READ (I also attached its code - see StrategyOrderBookLock). For test purposes there is only one strategyEntity existing in the system so every message from MDB modifies the same entity. Log entries are from different threads as Singleton invocation are served by different threads form Wildfly thread pool.

Comment: I don't have much experience with EJB, I'm using Spring. In Spring, configurations can override each other. If that's possible with EJB, then you should check whether the bean is defined twice, possibly with different scopes.

Answer (score 0):

The code itself looks pretty good and I can't find any obvious flaws. I remember having a similar situation myself a while ago where the log output didn't match what was in the database. Here is my situation:

- Log statement. This didn't log immediately; instead, the data was collected and a log event was added to a queue. This means the log event had a hard reference to the object.
- Insert/update of database
- End of transaction
- Second thread got object from the cache.
- Object was modified
- Another thread started to process the log events
- Log event was converted to string.

Since the object was modified before the last step, the log output was unexpected: The changes after the end of the transaction "leaked" into the logging.

Solution: Make sure the logger gets only immutable data. A simple workaround is

```
log.info("StrategyEntity after refresh: {}", startegyEntity.toString());
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clue but the main problem is not that logs differ from the state of entity in database. Main problem is that sometimes (very rarely) application reads old state from database and its logic flow from that point become corrupted. As a workaround (reasoning something wrong with ORM) I replaced database with simple Singleton cache. After this workaround application worked perfectly (all entities was stored in Singleton cache instead of storing them in database).

Comment: Currently I am thinking of replacing Hibernate (as default ORM in Wildfly) with EclipseLink and test if this issue is caused by ORM.